# Jewish Food Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Do questions about recipes for Jewish foods (i.e. "How is Ja7nun made?") fall within scope for Judaism.SE if they do not pertain to the brachah to be said?

Would it be possible to add them to scope if not?

Answer (score 3):

A question *about Judaism* is in scope. A question *not about Judaism* is not in scope. That's irrespective of whether it's also about recipes. Thus, [Seeking old Jewish recipes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3273) is not in scope (and correctly is closed); [What can I feed a vegetarian at my Pesach seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27011) and [charoses Ingredients](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6848)  and [Did the Terumas haDeshen write a challah recipe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16498) and [Alright you Yemenites or Mizrahim out there! Matzah Recipe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62142) are in scope (and correctly are not closed).